# Use usestate function in other components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to open modal on the product page with the useState(for this modal) stored on the Main page.

Main page:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import BannerSection from "../components/BannerSection/BannerSection";
import CarsSection from "../components/CarsSection/CarsSection";
import Modal from "../components/Modal/Modal";

const Main = () => {
  const [modalState, setModalState] = useState(false);
  const handleCloseModal = () => setModalState(false);
  const handleOpenModal = () => setModalState(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Modal showModal={modalState} closeModal={handleCloseModal} />
      <BannerSection openModal={handleOpenModal} />
      <CarsSection />
    </>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

Product item page

```
const CarProductDetails = () => {
// solution i did //
  const [modalState, setModalState] = useState(false);
  const handleCloseModal = () => setModalState(false);
  const handleOpenModal = () => setModalState(true);
  return (
    
    <>
    <Modal showModal={modalState} closeModal={handleCloseModal} />
//some code//
</>
export const CarProductDetails;
```

The solution i found is just copy modal useState to Product page and it works. But i feel it's not looking right. Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://betterprogramming.pub/create-a-custom-usemodal-react-hook-449b5909cc09 , basically creating a custom Hook for the modal logic, since will be the same in every component (the open close one)

Answer (score 0):

Passing state to children could be the solution in some scenarios.

If the sharing of state between components becomes too complex (for larger apps), it's recommended to use a state manager managing cross components state.

https://blog.openreplay.com/top-6-react-state-management-libraries-for-2022/

I like Redux personally https://redux.js.org/

If you go for Redux, this is a really nice library that will help you to structure everyting correctly -> https://redux-toolkit.js.org/

You can also use react context -> https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html depending on the scenarios. https://www.scalablepath.com/react/context-api-vs-redux#context-api-vs-redux-when-to-use-one-over-the-other

Answer (score 0):

If your **productpage** is a child component then you can **pass** your useState as **parameters** from parent to child

Answer (score 0):

Like this,the param "modalDataParams" is what you want to show in open modal.Maybe it's transfromed from a list-item or any others

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import BannerSection from "../components/BannerSection/BannerSection";
import CarsSection from "../components/CarsSection/CarsSection";
import Modal from "../components/Modal/Modal";

const Main = () => {
  const [modalState, setModalState] = useState(false);
  const [modalData, setModalData] = useState(false);
  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setModalState(false)
    setModalData(false);
  };
  const handleOpenModal = (data) =>{
    setModalState(true);
    setModalData(data);
    } 

  return (
    <>
      <Modal showModal={modalState} closeModal={handleCloseModal} />
      <BannerSection openModal={()=>handleOpenModal(modalDataParams)} />
      <CarsSection />
    </>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

And if you often use the Modal Functions.You can construct a modal compoment.
Like this:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Modal = (props) => {
  const {title,contentComponent,cancleEventFunc,confirmEventFunc} = props

  return (
  <>
  <ModalTitle title={title} />
  {contentComponent}
  <Row>
    <CancelBtn onClick={cancleEventFunc}/>
    <ConfirmBtn onClick={confirmEventFunc} />
  </Row>
  <>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

The props.contentComponent is a view component.So you custom and transform a view into the modal component.